# scrollTop issues when further down page

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I am using the below jquery to remove or add a class to a div (#sidebar) when the user scrolls away from the top of the page. As you can see I have the script set to only apply after 500 pixels have been cleared. This works perfectly at the top of the page, but if a user is further down the page (they can manually force #sidebar to appear) the script still removes the .active class but it ignores the 500 delay. I assume this is potentially a misuse of the scrollTop function but I'm not sure what to use instead. I have tried scroll but this breaks the script entirely.

Any advice greatly appreciated!

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2c07em1c/2/)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()>500) {
        $("#sidebar").removeClass("active");
    }
    else {
        $("#sidebar").addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Comment: can you explain what behaviour you want to achive?

Comment: what do you mean by further down the page? If the user is 100px down the #sidebar shouldnt have class right? It seems to work that way.

Comment: @CláudioBarreira What I mean by further down the page is that if the user finds themselves halfway down the page, the script doesn't behave as it would at the top of the page (i.e ignores the 100 delay). The #sidebar can be visible here as it can be manually expanded by clicking a button. Does that help?

Comment: @jacksbox hopefully the above explanation explains what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: yes I understand your problem, but I still can't reproduce it ... https://jsfiddle.net/2c07em1c/ , in jsfiddle your code works perfectly

Comment: @CláudioBarreira I have updated the fiddle to include the button that can manually show/hide #sidebar. Also made the delay 500. You'll notice the delay works when at top of page, but if user manually shows #sidebar when further down page the script still removes the .active class but ignores the delay? https://jsfiddle.net/2c07em1c/2/

Comment: Explanation is not sufficient. as @jacksbox said, explain the behavior you want?

Comment: @PankajDubey have updated the question with a little more info and a JSFiddle, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/hLaxxp3m/4/

```
var relativeY = $("#sidebar").offset().top - $(".line").offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(){

relativeY = $("#sidebar").offset().top - $(".line").offset().top;    
console.log(relativeY);
    if(relativeY >  500 || relativeY < -500 ) {
        $("#sidebar").removeClass("active");
        $(".line").css("top","0")
    }
    else {
        $("#sidebar").addClass("active");
    }
});
```

What I did was, I created a "line" element to test the position of the sidebar.. when they are 500px apart the sidebar disapears.When you click the toggle, the line moves to the position of the sidebar. With this code:

```
var topScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
$(".line").css("top",topScroll);
```

**UPDATE**

```
 $(".line").css("top","0")
```

added this line to the if statement, so when the sidebar disapears the line returns to the top until its called again by the click.

Comment: Hi @claudioBarreira. Thank you for this alternative approach, it is very close to what I need. Firstly however, I need the #sidebar to always re-appear when the user returns to the very top of the page. Secondly, I don't want the #sidebar to re-appear when a user returns to within 500px of the line established when they manually opened the #sidebar. In essence, once a scroll event occurs, the #sidebar should never re-appear unless the user returns to the top of the page. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help @claudioBarreira. That is now perfect, I really appreciate your time. I have now marked your answer as correct! Please upvote my question too! Have a great day.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
$(window).scrollTop()>100
```

try to use

```
$(document).scrollTop()>100
```

you can get some idea from this http://jsfiddle.net/gk78du6m/

try including this function

```
$('#sidebarToggle').click(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 200);
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't make any difference @Bhagyashree O. Any other ideas? Thank you for your help

Comment: Thanks @BhagyashreeO. Unfortuantely I dont want the #sidebarToggle element to return the user to the top of the page, it is supposed to expand the #sidebar in situ (no matter where you are vertically in the page). The problem is that once this is manually set to appear the delay on the scroll removeclass is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a global variable (currentTop) like-

```
/* Add a global variable */
var currentTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    /* Compare with "currentTop + 500" but not only "500" */
    if($(document).scrollTop() > currentTop + 500) {
        $("#sidebar").removeClass("active");
    }
    else if ($(document).scrollTop() <= 400) {
        $("#sidebar").addClass("active");
    }
});
```

And When you click the #sidebarToggle anchor then on click you can set `currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();` like-

```
sidebarToggle.onclick = function (e) {
        var active = 'active';
        /* Update currentTop like below */
        currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        e.preventDefault();
        toggleClass(sidebar, active);
        toggleClass(sidebarToggle, active);
    };
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hLaxxp3m/)

Comment: Thanks @pankajdubey, are you able to show if a JSFiddle as I can only make this achieve what I already have. Just to clarify, the issue is only when the user is halfway down the page and manually expands the #sidebar by clicking on #sidebarToggle (which adds the active class). When this has been done and the user again begins to scroll, the active class is removed but it is instant, rather than after a 500 delay.

Comment: let me know how that goes

Comment: Thanks. Still no delay when not at top of page, sidebar just collapses instantly?

Comment: Did you checked it on Fiddle? Its working fine for me. First you scrolled 400px and then #sidebar will disappear. Now you clicked on toggle sidebar and started scrolling again it will wait for you to scroll up to next 400px.

Comment: I updated the answer. Its working fine for me even on different browsers.

Comment: This is closer, thank you @pankajdubey. However, when further down the page the 400px is only supposed to act in one direction (to close the #sidebar). In this instance, if you scroll back up 400px the menu re-appears, but this is only supposed to happen if a) The user returns to the very top of the page or b) The user manually clicks #sidebarToggle. Any ideas?

Comment: Updated the answer. Use "else if ($(document).scrollTop() <= 400)" instead of "else"

Comment: Hi @pankajdubey, this is very close, thank you. There are two small issues remaining - here is the updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hLaxxp3m/2/.

Comment: a) When not at the top of the page, the scroll to close #sidebar only works when scrolling down, not up, the page. It would be perfect if it was effective for both directions.

b) When at the top of the page, initially the 500 delay works fine. However once the manual button has been used to open #sidebar further down the page, if a user then returns to the top and scrolls down again the #sidebar will remain open until the furthest point down the page the #sidebar has been manually triggered. It seems to always remember the last position.